# Time-independent Schroedinger equation is first order? Where did I go wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

I am attempting to solve the Schroedinger equation for a particle with potential energy:
$$V(x) = -Fx$$
The associated Hamiltonian is:
$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m} - Fq $$
In the Schroedinger representation, $p$ and $q$ are represented by the operators:
$$q = x \qquad p = -i\hslash \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  $$
Plugging in the standard $H\psi = E\psi$ yields:
$$ \psi '' = \left (  \frac{2m}{\hslash} (E-Fx)\right )\psi $$
Which I cannot solve.

However, if I instead use the momentum representation
$$ p = x \qquad q = i\hslash \frac \partial {\partial x} $$
the Hamiltonian becomes
$$ H = \frac{x^2}{2m} - F\frac \partial {\partial x} $$
Which means the Schroedinger equation becomes
$$ F \psi ' = \left ( \frac{x^2}{2m} - E \right ) \psi $$
Which is  a first-order equation.

Would solving this yield a valid wave function, or did I miss something on the way?

Also, how do I solve the fist case (the second order equation)?

Comment: If the second equation is valid (I'm not sure) you will get the wave function in the momentum space. To get $\psi(x)$ you need to compute the Fourier transform of the function you have got. And why I'm not sure the second equation is valid? Because the equation you call Schrödinger equation is actually the time indpedent Schrödinger equation. The Schrödinger equation is $H\psi =E\psi $. You should use here the momentum representation and see if you can use the separation variables method.

Comment: I actually only need to work with the momentum of the particle, so the momentum representation would be ideal. I know I am using the time-independent Schroedinger equation: there is no time-dependence in my problem. I am just puzzled by the fact that the resulting Schroedinger equation in momentum representation is only of the first order: does this not mean that the solution space is much smaller?

Comment: Your first equation is of the type $y''=-Cxy$ which is an Airy equation. You might lose degrees of freedom as the momentum equation gives you only bounded solutions, while the Airy equation also has unbounded solutions.

Comment: [Airy](https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~dlr/teaching/p443/LinearPotential.pdf).